# Elastic Beanstalk upload and deploy error: Error: Cannot find module 'semver'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

This is my first time uploading a Node.js/Express app to Elastic Beanstalk/AWS. The `server` folder uploaded fine. But on another environment, my `client` folder failed to load.

```
module.js:478
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:476:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/build/check-versions.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
```

I don't understand this error or the cause. Can anyone help?

It prompts to reinstall/upgrade node, but I don't believe I can do so on AWS ...

Full log:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log
-------------------------------------
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@1.0.0 start script 'node build/build.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the client package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node build/build.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs client
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls client
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/app/current/npm-debug.log

> client@1.0.0 start /var/app/current
> node build/build.js

module.js:478
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:476:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/build/check-versions.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)

npm ERR! Linux 4.14.62-65.117.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.14.3-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.14.3-linux-x64/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.14.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! client@1.0.0 start: `node build/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@1.0.0 start script 'node build/build.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the client package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node build/build.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs client
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls client
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/app/current/npm-debug.log

> client@1.0.0 start /var/app/current
> node build/build.js

module.js:478
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:476:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/build/check-versions.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)

npm ERR! Linux 4.14.62-65.117.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.14.3-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.14.3-linux-x64/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.14.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! client@1.0.0 start: `node build/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@1.0.0 start script 'node build/build.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the client package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node build/build.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs client
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls client
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/app/current/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was my own lack of knowledge about Node deployments. I was trying to upload my entire client folder.

What I should have done is run `npm run build` to create a `dist` file (using a long webpack script) and uploaded that to AWS. In that case, none of these dependencies are required as the files are served statically.